# How to restrict anyone (Root user also) to modify file in Linux?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, linux-kernel, security, selinux

I am developing one **security base software** for **LINUX platform** using `C` and `CPP`. I want to **restrict all users** even ***ROOT user*** also to modify the file. **i.e No one can modify the file**.

Modifying means **No one can** - **write** into the file, **move** the file or **remove** the file etc.

- *More precisely ---*

I have a **file** named as **a.txt** in directory `/home/` and I want to do something to this file so that **no one can write** into this file , **remove** this file or **move** this file.

**But can read the file.**

I tried `chattr` command -

> chattr +i /home/a.txt

It solved my problem for other users but when I switched to **superuser** i.e **ROOT user** into terminal and I fired command --

> chattr -i /home/a.txt

So `/home/a.txt` file become **mutable**.
So **ROOT user can change file immutable to mutable**. So **problem is not solved for ROOT user**.

So I want to do something to this file, so even root user can't modify this file. I hope my question is clear to you all. I am trying for this from last one month, but didn't got anything. Any suggestion and solution is appreciated.

Comment: SELinux perhaps. Or your own custom kernel module

Comment: @roaima I didn't get you. Will you please elaborate.

Comment: IMHO a lot harder than you think, because you have to freeze the whole directory tree (otherwise one would just erase the file or one of its parent directories and recreate his own). If you want to make sure the file is not altered, sign it in some way. But if the file cannot be altered, its contents could just be hard-coded in your software, or generated at compile time when installing the software on the system (see DKMS).

Comment: @xenoid Can please post any link so I can refer to this. If you have then please comment below.

Comment: The real solution here is not to give root access to users who can't be trusted with it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle No. That's not I want. One xyz company giving same problem solution into there product. So we can do also. That's why I am asking. I dot something  on-access kernel driver (Dazuko). If you have something regarding this , then please post it down.

Comment: *One xyz company giving same problem solution into there product.*  Really?  First, they can't - my computer, my file system, my kernel means **MY** files.  I want to change them, I can.  Full stop.  Second, tell us who you work for, so that we can completely avoid dealing with a company that thinks it's proper to put files on our computers that we aren't able to change at all, because given the first reason, that means they're incompetent, and second, I don't want anything to do with any company or developer that would want to do that in the first place.  Again: my computer, **MY** files.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If don't know then its okey. I will find my answer. The product I am working , its not for the personal computer user. Okey. ***Full stop.*** Its client requirement. ***Full Stop*** .

Comment: [Sony tried something like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal).  It went over really well.  And even then, it didn't work.  Because on **MY** computer, running **MY** kernel, accessing **MY** filesystem, if I want to change a file, I **CAN**.  The only way around that is to rootkit **MY** computer - and if you want to do that, you and your code simply can not be trusted.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you not satisfied then it's  okay, let it be. Some other geek will help me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Omkar SELinux is an option as mentioned by @roaima. Something like boot in `permissive` or `disabled` mode, define contexts and set restrictive policy on the file, reboot in `enforcing` mode (without the ability to switch to `permissive` from within running OS). But it's just a workaround, not a solution. You can't restrict a user with some knowledge from modifying files on his/her system unless it's under your administration.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Except that forcing people who want to install some software to run SELinux in enforcing mode isn't much better than openly admitting you're installing a rootkit. The overhead in properly administering customized SELinux configurations is not only substantial effort-wise, it can be very impactful as any mistake will likely render a system entirely unusable. I'd say the proper response to a product that wants me to run my systems with SELinux in enforcing mode with a custom configuration involves some combination of holy water, garlic, wooden stakes, and high explosives.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), actually, because you don't state your desired *outcome* here, and only ask about how to do something you *think* will get you your desired outcome.

Comment: ALSO, this is a repost of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198627/how-to-restrict-anyone-root-user-also-to-modify-file-in-linux) from Ask Ubuntu which was closed by the community.  (This said, this is an XY problem type question, so should probably be treated as such)

Comment: Dazuko appears to use a loadable kernel module. I don't know if it's loaded in the initramfs or after the regular `/` filesystem has been mounted, but in either case root can boot a kernel that doesn't contain that module.

Comment: A root user may also use [debugfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs), which scribbles directly on the disk device, to remove or clear the inode of any file.

Answer (score 3):

On a general purpose operating system, there is always a super user account that can ultimately do **and undo** anything (otherwise, you can't mitigate/clean a compromised system).

- The immutable attribute (`chattr +i`) is a good option to avoid mistake
- Mounting the filessytem as readonly is unpractical and ineffective (easy to undo)
- creating and using read-only filesystem is easy to override (overlay FS, or just use bind mount to another filesystem)
- Mandatory access control system (like SELinux) is the closest to what you want: a root shell in ([staff role](https://linux.die.net/man/8/staff_selinux) can't do perform some actions, but there's also a ([sysadm role](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sysadm_selinux) with more privileges)
- Even on the most paranoid system, the security will boil down to who have physical access to the system... to modify the [kernel boot command](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-enabling_and_disabling_selinux-dracut-parameters) like (this applies to Android devices)

Comment: I think **may be** SELinux will solve my problem. Will please share any repository or any website so I can start with. I surfed some website but didn't get anything important.

Comment: SELinux is giving security I understood. But it is securing whole system as per user basis. I read whole documents regarding this here ->> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts . I want to secure one file or one directory not whole system. Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be create a partition with `luks` that is encrypted with a password.

**EDIT**:
Another approach can be use `IPFS` to store the file.

Comment: I also want to read the file . Restriction is just can't modify. But we should read the file. If we encrypt then we can't read the file.

Comment: You need to encrypt and the crypt the partition at runtime from the software

Comment: Sounds pretty much like you should find a clean and _really_ secure way to achieve your goal…

Comment: @Omkar I think you should define your *outcome*. You have some problem, and to solve that problem, you think you need an immutable file. However, if you state your *real* problem, there may be other solutions you have not considered, and your current approach may have flaws that you are not aware of.

Comment: @vidarlo I totally appreciated your suggestion. But my main motive is to, suppose I have file a.txt and if I made this file mutable then no one should modify it. Or no one should have permission to make mutable again except my application.

Comment: @Omkar but ***why*** do you need an immutable file? Would signing it, and performing an integrity check be a good alternative? Do you need to protect against root editing the underlying block device? Is it a system that you own?

Comment: dear @vidarlo I don't want this facility but my client wants. So I have to provide this functionality any how. I know root can access anything but where I am deploying this software there is administrator and clients network at there firm. And they are saving one file into every system and don't want to get deleted by employee that's why they want this feature. In depth why they want this feature I don't know. But any how I need to give solution on this.

Comment: @omkar you should probably inform your client that they should remove root permissions from untrusted users. The client is not always right...

Comment: Maybe IPFS can help here.

Comment: IPFS would be very similar to calculating the hash of the file and hardcoding the hash into the program